# php update query on android always going to else statment

Tags: java, php, android

My Java class always goes to the else statement even I put the right details and call the right fields. Please help me.

Below is my code. It doesn't have a problem with the `getintents` and I don't know where the problem is.

## update.php

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['txtCar_No']) &&  isset($_POST['txtCarModel']) && 
isset($_POST['txtCarType']) && isset($_POST['txtCapacity']) && 
isset($_POST['image']) && isset($_POST['txtFuelType']) && 
isset($_POST['txtPlateNumber']) &&  isset($_POST['txtcarPrice']))
{
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
$id = $now->format('YmdHis');

$upload_folder = "upload";
$path = "$upload_folder/$id.jpeg";
$image = $_POST['image'];
$fullpath = "http://carkila.esy.es/$upload_folder/$id.jpeg";

$Car_No = $_POST['txtCar_No'];
$Car_Model = $_POST['txtCarModel'];
$Car_Type = $_POST['txtCarType'];
$Capacity = $_POST['txtCapacity'];
$Fuel_Type = $_POST['txtFuelType'];
$PlateNumber = $_POST['txtPlateNumber'];
$carPrice = $_POST['carPrice'];

$query = "UPDATE tbl_cars SET Car_Model='$Car_Model', Car_Type='$Car_Type', Capacity='$Capacity', fuelType='$Fuel_Type' ,carPlatenuNumber='$PlateNumber', image='$fullpath' , carPrice = '$carPrice' WHERE Car_No='$Car_No'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if($result > 0){
    echo "success";
    exit;
}
else{
    echo"failed";
    exit;
}
}

?>
```

## UpdateClick.java

```
public class UpdateClick extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText etCarModel;
EditText etCarType;
EditText etCapacity;
EditText etPlateNumber;
EditText etPrice;
ImageView ivImg;
Spinner spFuelType;
TextView tvCar_No;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
Button btnSelectPhoto,btnUpdate;
GalleryPhoto galleryPhoto;
Bitmap bitmap;
final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1231;
String selectedPhoto;
String e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,i1,e7;


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            galleryPhoto.setPhotoUri(uri);
            String photoPath = galleryPhoto.getPath();
            selectedPhoto = photoPath;
            try {
                bitmap = com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
                ivImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong while opening gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_click);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
    galleryPhoto = new GalleryPhoto(getApplicationContext());
    spFuelType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spFuelType);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.fuel_types,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spFuelType.setAdapter(adapter);
    spFuelType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(UpdateClick.this));

    etCarModel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCarModel);
    etCarType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCarType);
    etCapacity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCapacity);
    etPlateNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlateNumber);
    etPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPrice);
    tvCar_No = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCar_No);
    ivImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImg);
    btnSelectPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);

    final Cars Cars = (Cars)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("cars");

    Intent in = getIntent();
    e1 = in.getStringExtra("e1");
    e2 = in.getStringExtra("e2");
    e3 = in.getStringExtra("e3");
    e4 = in.getStringExtra("e4");
    e5 = in.getStringExtra("e5");
    e6 = in.getStringExtra("e6");
    e7 = in.getStringExtra("e7");
    i1 = in.getStringExtra("i1");


    etCarModel.setText(e1);
    etCarType.setText(e2);
    etCapacity.setText(e3);
    etPlateNumber.setText(e5);
    etPrice.setText(e6);
    tvCar_No.setText(e7);
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(i1,ivImg);

    btnSelectPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(galleryPhoto.openGalleryIntent(), GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        bitmap = com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.ImageLoader.init().from(selectedPhoto).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
        String encodeImage = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap);
        HashMap<String, String> post = new HashMap<String, String>();
        post.put("image", encodeImage);
        PostResponseAsyncTask taskUpload = new PostResponseAsyncTask(UpdateClick.this, post, new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, s);
                if (s.contains("upload_success")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Upload Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Uploading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        taskUpload.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/upload1.php");
        taskUpload.setEachExceptionsHandler(new EachExceptionsHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleIOException(IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Connect to Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void handleMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void handleProtocolException(ProtocolException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Protocol Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void handleUnsupportedEncodingException(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Encoding Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong while choosing photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    HashMap postData = new HashMap();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etCarModel.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(UpdateClick.this, "Car model is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etCarType.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(UpdateClick.this, "Car type is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etCapacity.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(UpdateClick.this, "Capacity is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etPlateNumber.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(UpdateClick.this, "Plate Number is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etPrice.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(UpdateClick.this, "Price is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }


    postData.put("txtCar_No",tvCar_No.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtCarModel", etCarModel.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtCarType", etCarType.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtCapacity", etCapacity.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtPlateNumber", etPlateNumber.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtCarPrice", etPrice.getText().toString());
    postData.put("image", toString());
    postData.put("txtFuelType", spFuelType.getSelectedItem().toString());

    PostResponseAsyncTask taskPost = new PostResponseAsyncTask(UpdateClick.this, postData, new AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String s) {
            Log.d("asdqwe", s);
                if (s.contains("success")) {
                    Toast.makeText(UpdateClick.this, "Post Updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent in = new Intent(UpdateClick.this, OwnerTabs.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


        }
    });

    taskPost.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/update.php");
}

}
```

Comment: i believe if you echo the query the values will be empty.  Change all the values like this Car_Model='$Car_Model' -> Car_Model='".$Car_Model."'

Comment: olso change the if condition. if(!$result){
    echo"failed";
    exit;
}
else{
    echo"Success";
    exit;
}

Comment: change `if($result > 0)` to `if(!empty($result))`

Comment: @RafaelShkembi still giving me nothing sir :c

Comment: @VivekSingh still giving me nothing sir :(

Comment: @B.Dee please check if query is executing or not

Comment: @VivekSingh its not executing its echoes nothing. not `success` nor `failed`

Answer (score 0):

[From the manual on `mysqli_query`](http://php.net/mysqli-query)

> Returns **FALSE** on failure. For successful *SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN* queries `mysqli_query()` will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return **TRUE**.

If you take a look at the [type comparison truth table in the manual](http://php.net/types.comparisons) you'll see that `false > 0 === false`, which means that if the condition is always false then `mysqli_query()` is always returning false, which means that `mysqli_query()` is ***always*** failing each time you call this query.

You should **always** use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var-dump) for debugging variables in PHP as it provides more useful information than `echo`, `print`, or `print_r`, becasue `print false`, `print_r(false)` and `echo false` all give you nothing in output, which isn't useful for debugging purposes, but `var_dump(false)` does.

In your case the most likely cause is a syntax error in your SQL since you're blindly concatenting input into your SQL code without [proper escaping](http://php.net/mysqli-real-escape-string) or using [prepared queries](http://php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements).

You can also check [`mysqli::$error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get more useful error information from your database in PHP when your queries fail.